# Which is the way to add MVC behavior to existing classes?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, poco

I have a Windows Form project that I would like to migrate toward a web application using ASP.NET MVC2.

In this project I have some POCO classes as in this example that are part of a class library and that I would like to use with a binary reference

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime BornDate { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Is there a way to use these classes inside my Web MVC project and adding, for example validation attributes without modifying the original assembly?

thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/). It integrates nicely with [ASP.NET MVC](http://schotime.net/blog/index.php/2009/05/11/fluent-validation-model-binder-aspnet-mvc/) and allows you to unobtrusively add validation rules without modifying your POCO objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can add Meta Information like Validation by using a Partial Class

```
namespace xxx.Data.yyy
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(Posting_Validation))]
    public partial class Posting { 
    }

    public class Posting_Validation {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Need title")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Must be under 50 characters")]
        [DisplayName("Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Display(AutoGenerateField = false)]
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
        public int PostingId { get; set; }

        [UIHint("tiny_mce")]
        public string HtmlContent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The MetadataType attribute should go to the original POCO class?

Comment: Well...That's out of scope for me because it breaks compatibility with the window form project that I should continue to support. That's the way I have stated "without modifying the origina assembly"... Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: You don't have to modify your original assembly! You just extending it in your own code!

Comment: Sorry but I did not understand. If I have to decorate the original class with an attribute why you're saying that I dont have to modify the original assembly? Do you mean by using the partial class modifier? And how this work if the original class has not the  partial modifier?